# Why is there an invalid argument error from the last error handler in the following code?

Tags: http, go

The following code should create a new file, copy the contents of the resp.Body to the file and close the file and body afterwards

```
out, _ := os.Create(fname) 
defer out.Close()

resp, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error getting File ", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

if _, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "invalid argument" from this part: if _, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

Comment: It works wonderfully well for me.

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid value for fname?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have specified an invalid fname value. Try intercepting error there:

```
out, err := os.Create(fname)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
defer out.Close()

resp, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error getting File ", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

if _, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: Could it be because fname has an underscore in it? e.g. hello_world

Comment: @harry_h, No. I don't know what your OS is and fname is. Would you care to share.